# How to use windows printer in Ubuntu

Tags: printing, samba

im trying to configure printer in my Ubuntu 22.04. Printer is connected via  USB to Windows 10 machine, SMB features are enable on it as well. At Ubuntu machine I have installed samba so I have an access to windows network. Ubuntu found printer at windows IP and everything seems to be ok but if I want to print anything there is "Authorization Required" prompt and ask me for creditentials (which one? from Linux or Windows? Nothing works). Additionaly in printer is status: "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED"... I was reading a lot of topics about that .... please help. Here is the view of
[windows network from ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzf1w.png)

Answer (score 0):

This credentials is for Windows share which should contain printer so you have to provide correct Windows credentials for user who can manage this printer (have enough admin rights).

You have to make sure that printer is shared and visible in shared directory.

Win+R > type "control printers" and enter > right click on Proporties > Sharing > Check all 3 boxes - propably the most important is "List in the directory".

Connect to your Windows from Ubuntu "Other" location pane and at the very bottom fill up PC name via NetBIOS name or IP precended by
smb://yourPC

For example:
smb://myworkstation

Hit connect button and provide Windows creds.
You should saw shared printer.

The same style you can add new printer under Settings with the same Samba url.

Comment: Thank You for answer. On windows machine everything seems to be enabled, any other Windows machine can print without problems... On ubuntu I have a view of windows machine (edited my question and added screen), I can even add printer but all the time I have "unauthorized" prompt everytime I want to print.

Comment: You can try downgrade Samba version https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-samba-to-use-smbv2-and-disable-smbv1-on-linux-or-unix/ with "client max protocol".

Comment: OK I did It! After long hours and many articles I have fixed It. If I create on windows a local (withous MS Account) user, I can use Its creditentials to give Ubuntu required authorization... everything seems to be working :) thank You all For Your time!